# Criando arquivo Json com PHP. Tirar ultima virgula

Tags: php, json

Estou criando um arquivo Json, mas preciso remover a ultima virgula do coxete referente ao ultimo registro.

Esse json, será usado no **DataTable**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
{
  "data": [
    <?php foreach ($rs as $row): ?>
      [
        "<?= $row['ID_Receita']; ?>",
        "<?= $row['nome']; ?>",
        "<?= $row['valor']; ?>",
        "<?= $row['dataVenci']; ?>",
        "<?= $row['formaEntrada']; ?>"
      ],
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  ]
}
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: @AngeloSoares como seria a forma correta de montar esse json?

Comment: A forma correta é montar uma array no PHP e passar um [`json_encode`](https://php.net/json_encode) nela. Isso que você está fazendo pode dar errado de várias maneiras diferentes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso tá com cara de ser um JS gerado pelo PHP, correto? Para inicializar o DataTables, se entendi bem.

O mais simples e correto é usar a função [`json_encode`](https://php.net/json_encode) do PHP para gerar um JSON válido a partir de um array. Assim:

```
<?php
// monte essa array a partir do banco de dados
$dados = [
    ["1", "Tiago", "300.00", "etc"],
    // demais linhas
];
?>

<script>
// seu código js
// ...
{
    "data": <?php echo json_encode($dados); ?>
}
// ...
</script>
```